# Slow SVG rendering when setting src

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I am having a problem when rendering SVG images to canvas. When I generate the svg markup and add it to the src of a new image then render that image to the canvas I get terrible performance. My app drops from real time to unusable. But if I save the same markup as an svg file and load that as an image it runs perfectly.

```
var svgText = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="239" height="268" id="testSVG" >
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id='grad2262398' x1='0' y1='0' x2='0' y2='1'>
    <stop offset='0.0' stop-color='#bcbbbb'/>
    <stop offset='1.0' stop-color='#d2a796'/>
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path d="M 158.5 9.0 L 225.0 97.5 L 208.5 111.0 L 141.0 23.5 L 158.5 9.0 M 118.5 44.0 L 203.0 114.5 L 189.5 132.0 L 104.0 61.5 L 118.5 44.0 M 85.5 90.0 L 185.5 136.0 L 178.0 155.5 L 76.5 111.0 L 85.5 90.0 M 67.5 141.0 L 174.5 163.0 L 171.0 185.0 L 62.5 163.0 L 67.5 141.0 M 16.0 168.0 L 38.0 168.0 L 38.0 234.0 L 192.0 234.0 L 192.0 168.0 L 215.0 168.0 L 215.0 256.0 L 16.0 256.0 L 16.0 168.0 M 60.0 190.0 L 171.0 190.0 L 171.0 213.0 L 60.0 213.0 L 60.0 190.0 "  style="fill:url(#grad2262398);"/>
    </svg>`
var image = new Image();
image.src = svgText;  // this runs very slowly

//while 
var image = new Image();
image.src = "svgText.svg"; // this renders as fast as a simillar sized bitmap image
                           // yet the content is exactly the same.
```

Above is just an example of how the SVG is formated, the problem does not become an issue until the points in the path get to the several thousand. I can render a SVG with 100K+ points in real-time when loaded from a file, as a Javascript string I get less then 2 frames a second.

How can I fix this and still have the auto generated path content available so I can modify it when needed.

Comment: Where are you testing it (which browser)? Also, can you provide a working JSFiddle or similar?

Comment: @Cedric Reichenbach I am using Chrome latest Dev version.

Comment: Do you see the same problem in other browsers, e.g. Firefox?

Comment: App only runs in Chrome so I do not know if it is the same in other browsers.